# Trouble to fetch data from JSON

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Am working in jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.
Currently I have a Trouble to fetch data from JSON.

My JSON format is ;

```
{
    payment: {
        1: "Visa",
        2: "American Express",
        3: "Mastercard/Eurocard",
        4: "Visa – Verified by Visa",
        5: "Mastercard/Eurocard – Securecode"
    }
}
```

And Its XML will looks like this ;

```
   <payment>

       <1>Visa</1>

       <2>American Express</2>

       <3>Mastercard/Eurocard</3>

       <4>Visa – Verified by Visa</4>

       <5>Mastercard/Eurocard – Securecode</5>

   </payment>
```

**I want to fetch the details in to a selectbox.** 
and My Code is ;

```
function loadpayment() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.sample.net/json/jsn_payments.php?json=1&rcg_mobile=2',
        data: '',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var count = data.payment.length;
            var card_type_ = $('#card_type_');
            var card_type = '';
            card_type_.empty();
            card_type += '<option selected="selected" value="">' + BookCar2_Cardtype_label + '</option>';

            for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                card_type += '<option value=' + data.payment.[i] + '>' + data.payment.[i] + '</option>';
                alert(data.payment.payment[i]);
                alert(0);
            }
            card_type_.append(card_type);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

But Its not working !!! I thinks its a simple mistake but i lost lot of time to solve this issue.. so please help me :(

Comment: What's not working? Are you seeing any error messages in the console?

Comment: Actually I worked in DreamWeaver and Import to Eclipse. and when I use that code its shows Syntax Error.. :(

Comment: What syntax error specifically? Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: See Onur TOPAL's answer. It's your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use the json as in the question you cannot access them as property beacuse it is a number remember you cannot define number variable. or cannot access it like array as it is an object.

but it s and object with key so you should be able to acces them like below

```
obj["1"], obj["2"] etc
```

in your case try `data.payment[i]` or just in case `data.payment[i.toString()]`

also just notices you are using for loop as it s an array but it not so `data.payment.length` returns undefined. you should use foreach loop for payment, try below code.

```
for (var key in data.payment)
{
   card_type += '<option value=' + data.payment[key] + '>' + data.payment[key] + '</option>';
                alert(data.payment[key]);
                alert(0);
}
```

Comment: You do not need to explicitly cast to string when accessing properties.  `obj["1"]` is the same as `obj[1]`, and the call to `i.toString()` is also not needed..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for loop, use $.each()

```
$.each(data.payment,function(key,option)
{
  card_type_.append('<option value="'+key+'">'+option+'</option>');
});
```

Other than that, I would say data.payment.[i] should be data.payment[i]

*and as cfs pointed out the missing quotes for value=""

Comment: Am really sorry to ask this ; wht u mean by "key,option" ?

Comment: I already tried data.payment[i] before posting this Q.. but no data displayed in selectbox.. thats the prblm !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly what error you're seeing, but I can see that the HTML you are creating is not valid: you're missing quotes around the value attribute in your `option` elements.

**EDIT** You are also accessing your arrays incorrectly. You don't need a dot between the `data.payment` and the `[i]`

Try this instead:

```
card_type += '<option value="' + data.payment[i] + '">' + data.payment[i] + '</option>';
```

Comment: when we use this type of method .. its shows the Syntax error.. :(

Comment: @ULLASMOHAN.V I updated my answer to address what might be causing your syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I have put your JSON code inside a JSONLinter and it seems your JSON code is invalid. 
You should use this code instead:

```
{
    "payment": [
        "Visa",
        "American Express",
        "Mastercard/Eurocard",
        "Visa – Verified by Visa",
        "Mastercard/Eurocard – Securecode"
    ]
}
```

You can also use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) instead of the "for".

Comment: Yeah.. But this Code is send from Client.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the Solution :-)

And My code is :

```
 function loadpayment(){

$.ajax({ 

 url: 'https://www.sample.net/json/jsn_payments.php?json=1&rcg_mobile=2',
 data:'',
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "json",
 crossDomain:true,
 cache: false,
 async:false,
 success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

     var count = data.payment.length;
      //alert(count);
     var card_type_=$('#card_type_'); 
     var card_type = '';
     card_type_.empty();
     card_type +='<option selected="selected" value="">'+BookCar2_Cardtype_label+'</option>';
    for (var key in data.payment)
    {
        card_type += '<option value=' + data.payment[key] + '>' + data.payment[key] + '</option>';

    }

    card_type_.append(card_type);


},

 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(textStatus +"-"+ errorThrown);}
```

});

}

**Thank you.. @ Onur TOPAL!!**